# Examples of constinit declaration not reachable at the point of the initializing declaration

Tags: c++, c++20, constinit

From [dcl.constinit](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.constinit):

> No diagnostic is required if no constinit declaration is reachable at the point of the initializing declaration.

What does it mean? I guess an example would be sufficient.

Something dynamically initialized is just ill-formed (from the same link), so it's not that.

Comment: @273K so what's the answer?

Comment: The previous sentence says that a constinit variable must be declared constinit in the initialization. What if it is declared constinit in one file and initialized in another file - without the keyword? "No diagnostic required".

Comment: https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1143r2.html See **Applying constinit to declarations or just definitions?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you have one translation unit that declares a symbol to be `constinit`:

```
// a.cc

#include <iostream>

extern constinit bool has_constinit;

int
main()
{
  std::cout << std::boolalpha << has_constinit << std::endl;
}
```

Now suppose the translation unit that defined the symbol does not declare it `constinit`:

```
// b.cc

#include <cstdlib>

bool has_constinit = std::getenv("CONSTINIT");
```

You can compile and link these two files together without error, even though it doesn't do what you wanted, because `has_constinit` is being initialized dynamically.